# Force application to only be able to save files in a specific folder

Tags: permissions

I want to force an application (like gedit) so that it can only save files in one specific folder (like ~/bla). Sort of like a prison where you can only save files.

I already thought about modifying gtk's source to force it, or using openroot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do:

1. Run gedit as a user that only has the ability to write to the one folder.
2. Change the source code of gedit to reject saving to any other folder but the one you want and recompile it.

Comment: Actually 1 is a pretty good idea, thought of it before.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this personally but I believe that you can accomplish this using [SELinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SELinux).